# Which one is gone in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The appetizing plate of cookies was gone in half an hour.

In this sentence, which one is gone, the cookies or the plate?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's *the plate of cookies* that was gone. The whole thing. The plate *and* the cookies on it. Most likely because the cookies had been eaten and the empty plate removed, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookies are gone. A plate **of** something, usually food, is considered to mean not the plate, but whatever is on it.

> plate noun [countable]
>
> also plateful
>   an amount of food on a plate:
>
> Stephen ate three plates of spaghetti.

[Plate (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plate)

Comment: This is correct.  While, yes, it *could* be the plate (leaving the cookies) as a kind of humorous "subversion of expectation", or possibly both the plate and the cookies together, in any ordinary context the reader would assume the cookies were gone and the plate remained.   After all, it's not the *plate* that is "appetizing".

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous. So we must use context to interpret the meaning. While it could either mean the cookies were eaten, or someone stole the whole plate of cookies,  In any normal context it means the cookies have been eaten, especially as we know the cookies were delicious and so likely to be eaten quickly. Compare:

> Waste services are really good in this city. I put a bag of rubbish out and it was gone in half an hour.

Here the context would suggest the opposite, the bag (and the rubbish) was taken.

Comment: It's ambiguous, yes, but in any ordinary context, the cookies are gone and the plate remains.   Any other interpretation is a humorous play on expectation, along the lines of "I shot an elephant in my pajamas".

Comment: I thought I'd written that, but re-reading it seems that I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it's *the plate of cookies* that was gone. The whole thing. The plate *and* the cookies on it.

Most likely this is because the cookies had been eaten and the empty plate removed, but not necessarily. It could also be that nobody liked the cookies (nobody wanted to eat them) and everything was taken away again.

There is nothing in the statement that explains the history of what happened or the intention behind it.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers:  There is a joke possible in the ambiguity of your sentence, especially since you put "appetizing" before "plate".  Of course any rational person would assume it isn't the *plate* that is appetizing, but some people may not be so particular.

[image]

(Okay, that's probably a frisbee that Cookie Monster is eating, and not a plate, but you get the idea.)

This is a typical style of English humor, which plays against what is expected from the syntax.  An example of this is a classic joke from the comedian Groucho Marx:

> [One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas.  How he got in my pajamas I don't know.](https://youtu.be/FZUfhfHbjE4?t=124)

The joke is that we *expect* he shot an elephant while he was still dressed in his pajamas, but the ambiguity of the sentence means it's possible that it was the *elephant* who was wearing the pajamas.

In any case, if you wanted to be perfectly clear that it was the *cookies* that were tasty, you could write:

> The plate of **appetizing cookies** was gone in half an hour.

but where's the fun in that?